# Google Admob API - Java client - com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, google-api, admob

I'm trying to use Google Admob API Java client, described [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/libraries) but I got this response:

```
{
  "code" : 0,
  "error" : {
    "code" : 403,
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors" : [ {
      "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
      "domain" : "global",
      "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
    } ],
    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

This is how I get credentials:

```
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
            new InputStreamReader(GoogleConnector.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets_tt.json")));
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report")).setDataStoreFactory(
            dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize(userId);
```

This is my Admob client:

```
AdMob adMobClient = new AdMob.Builder(
        httpTransport,
        jsonFactory,
        request -> {
            credential.initialize(request);
            request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(jsonFactory));
        })
        .setRootUrl("https://admob.googleapis.com")
        .setApplicationName(applicationName)
        .build();
return adMobClient;
```

And I also added manually scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report in OAuth consent screen.

Can someone help me or suggest what the cause of this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the credentials stored previously by the *DataStore* (I.e., check the directory like ~/.credentials/ in your home). Go through the full flow again.

In OAuth flow:

- the code generates link;

  - open it in incognito browse mode;
  - login with your **AdMob account**;
  - accept the consonant screen (with your **admob account**);
- receive the *access_token* and *refresh_token*;
- store the *refresh_roken* with data store;
- make request with *access_token*;

Most of the steps would be done by *GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow* code.

Also, you can check the java sample on github:

- https://github.com/mprokhorenko/googleads-admob-examples/tree/master/java